# Get Row Data From BLE and convert it into Dictionary

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I am trying to get row advertisement data form BLE device. Please can you let me know how to convert row data to actual data.

```
BLE Row Advertisement Data
{   
     kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 0;
     kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <1801beac 2f234454 cf6d4a0f adf2f491 1ba9ffa6 00010002 be00>;
}
```

Comment: If `advertisement` is what you printed, then `NSData *data = advertisement[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]`. Now I don't know what you want to do with that (what is that supposed to be?). Is that what you asked for?

Comment: @Larme Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/q/51205362/4053741