# Not getting full BLE peripheral Name

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am getting Data from BLE Device by Delegate

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI

But i am not getting full peripheral.name form this method. 
My BLE Device name is - d7bce65 3fa1b4bf 
But I am getting - d7bce65 (name is truncated by sapce)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Advertising data is limited to 31 bytes. Besides the local name, your device is probably sending other information like service UUIDs. When all the info doesn’t fit in the 31 byte payload, the local name gets truncated.

You can learn the basics of advertising data here. 
https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2017/02/10/bluetooth_advertisin-hGsf

Comment: This issue is due to space. Ohterwise I am getting eeb4f646c8d79c7d3fa properly form other BLE device..

Comment: What's still not clear is how you're supposed to get the full name. Are you supposed to explicitly ask for it from the Generic Access service? Because that service doesn't show up in the service list when doing discovery, so without a reference to the CBService etc I'm not sure how you get the full name.

Comment: The Bluetooth 5.0 spec added Extended Advertisements to allow larger data sets in an advertisement. Obviously this is contingent upon both your advertising device being _able_ to support it and it actually doing so.

https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-advertisements/     I believe that CoreBluetooth will automatically aggregate all of the advertising information into the `advertisementData` parameter in the callback you referenced.